# How to add DRM to a Live-Streaming URL?

Tags: streaming, drm

I want to add DRM to a Live-Streaming URL. I have setup a Live Streaming with NGINX in a EC2 instance. So is it possible to add DRM to the Live Streaming ? If anyone have any suggestion please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You will find a detailed description in the article
[Building a live video streaming website - Part 3 - DRM](https://benwilber.github.io/nginx/rtmp/live/video/streaming/django/drm/2018/10/20/building-a-live-video-streaming-website-part-3-drm.html).
You may also find as interesting the other parts of this series.

I will not copy-paste here all the scripts contained in the article.
I will only remark that:

- You'll need to install the modules: ngx_devel_kit, set-misc-nginx-module,
  ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
- nginx-rtmp will encrypt MPEG-TS segments
- The scripts will produce 10 second segments and encrypt every 6 segments
  with a new encryption key, so every 1 minute of video requires re-authorization to view
- Only logged-in, authorized viewers will be able to watch the video streams.